# NoSuchMethodError: optionsBuilder.build().getService() in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: java, spring, maven, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to connect to google bucket to upload a file.

```
StorageOptions.Builder optionsBuilder = StorageOptions.newBuilder();

optionsBuilder.setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault());

Storage storage = optionsBuilder.build().getService();
```

I have provided service account in environment variables and when i looked into optionsBuilder.build() the credentials are added correctly including projectId, credentials etc. but `service` property is showing null.

its giving error for `optionsBuilder.build().getService()` and returns

`com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClient$Builder.setBatchPath(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/services/AbstractGoogleClient$Builder;`

Here are the maven dependencies related to google cloud

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-datastore</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Letme know if there is any workaround for it

Comment: Can you specify your environment in order to be able to reproduce the same from my side. Anyway, if you are using Google App Engine Java there is this documentation [1] by Google about using Cloud Storage with Java.
About Spring with Cloud Storage, there are these [2] examples you can follow.


  [1]: https://cloud.google.com/java/getting-started/using-cloud-storage
  [2]: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/tree/master/spring-cloud-gcp-samples/spring-cloud-gcp-storage-resource-sample

Comment: @TasosV thanks for reply, I found the solution. I have added `google-api-client:1.23.0`, `google-http-client-jackson2:1.23.0`, `google-http-client:1.23.0` dependencies it got fixed. source: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/issues/325#issuecomment-377171975